# error while migrating with foreign key in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, migration, laravel-8

I am trying to migrate below function but it gives me same error everytime, i failed to find out the reason, even I tried the other syntax from documentation

//up function

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id('cat_id');
            $table->string('cat_name');
            $table->string('cat_desc');
            $table->string('cat_image');
            $table->timestamps();
        });



Schema::create('sellers', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id('seller_id');
        $table->string('seller_name');
        $table->string('seller_desc');
        $table->string('seller_image');
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id('prd_id');
        $table->string('prd_name');
        $table->string('prd_price');
        $table->string('prd_image');
        $table->string('prd_desc');
        $table->foreignId('product_cat_id')->constrained('categories');
        $table->foreignId('product_seller_id')->constrained('sellers');
        $table->boolean('prd_status');
        $table->timestamps();
    });

}
```

//error

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table
> ecommerce.products (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly
> formed") (SQL: alter table products add constraint
> products_product_cat_id_foreign foreign key (product_cat_id)
> references categories (id))

i have also delete the migration file from database and do fresh migration but it didn't help, pls guide me, thanks in advance

Comment: When you have custom ID names use the more detailed declaration >  $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because, on your `categories` and `sellers` both table **primary key** are not `id`, by default **[constrained](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints)** method uses the `id` as primary key as foreign key reference, so change  :

```
$table->foreignId('product_cat_id')->constrained('categories');
$table->foreignId('product_seller_id')->constrained('sellers');
```

to,

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('product_cat_id');
$table->foreign('product_cat_id')->references('cat_id')->on('categories');

$table->unsignedBigInteger('product_seller_id');
$table->foreign('product_seller_id')->references('seller_id')->on('sellers');
```

If you're using Model, then also define your [primary key](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#primary-keys) on your model like  :

```
protected $primaryKey = 'cat_id';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('cat_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('cat_name');
            $table->string('cat_desc');
            $table->string('cat_image');
            $table->timestamps();
        });



Schema::create('sellers', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('seller_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('seller_name');
        $table->string('seller_desc');
        $table->string('seller_image');
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('prd_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('prd_name');
        $table->string('prd_price');
        $table->string('prd_image');
        $table->string('prd_desc');
        $table->foreignId('product_cat_id')->constrained('categories');
        $table->foreignId('product_seller_id')->constrained('sellers');
        $table->boolean('prd_status');
        $table->timestamps();
    });

}
```